# Delete the checkout botton in sidebar

Tags: wordpress, widget, woocommerce

I want to remove the woo commerce checkout botton on the right widgetbar which says Kasse. http://vinesso.dk/produkt-kategori/vine/

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i cant see a Kasse button? is it only there if you are logged in?

On a side note, in wordpress you can edit the content of a plugin though once you update the plugin it will be overwritten and you will be starting from scratch again. I personally would find the class of said button and hide it with CSS.

Comment: actually! found it... turns out you need to select an item to put in your checkout to get the button up.

.widget_shopping_cart .wc-forward {display:none}

That would hide it for you if you place that in your main CSS. Or you can open the plugin in wordpress and edit it through there.

Comment: thank you for your answer! it doesn't work when I put the .widget_shopping_cart .wc-forward {display:none} in the CSS. And I can't find it in the button in the plugin edit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried putting !important after the display:none? the CSS for the widget could be overriding your base CSS

.widget_shopping_cart .wc-forward {display:none !important}

Comment: It works now, but now it just hide both buttons. Is it possible to keep the 'Se kurv' button?

Comment: No problem glad i could help!

Could you just mark this answer as the answer and then everything will be finished on here :) just hit the tick on the left hand side of this answer.

Thanks!